# add UIView overlay to UIIMagePickerController video recording

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

i want to use `UIIMagePickerController` to record video as i would normally do.
but i want to add a layer (`UIView`) that needs to be captured within the video overlay.
lets sat i have a star spinning on my view. when i will take the video i will see the star spinning as i am recording and when finish recording the same output will be.

i know this object has a property :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraOverlayView
```

but i think it needs to manage only the buttons that would not be captured.

what is the normal\recommended approach to manage such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can add your custom overlay view and UIImagePickerController.view as subviews to one view.
User startVideoCapture and stopVideoCapture to do your task.
Sample codes:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    picker.delegate = self;
    self.videoPicker    = picker;
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoPicker.view];
```

Of course, if you do this, the control of flash lights should be done by yourself.

Comment: what exactly is the self.videoPicker?

Comment: That's a property object to keep the UIImagePickerController. Retain of course

Comment: its not recording the overlay layer